# Why calling vprintf or similar functions twice does not work or even segfaults?

Tags: c, linux, segmentation-fault, variadic-functions

I got a segmentation fault in my program and was able to reliably reproduce it in this simple example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <syslog.h>
#include <stdarg.h>

// if I remove at least one of the args, segfault does not happen
void doLog(unsigned int arg0, unsigned int arg1, unsigned int arg2, const char* format, ...)
{
    va_list args;

    va_start(args, format);
    // by default - to both console and syslog
    vprintf(format, args);

    // next v* function call causes segfault, no matter if vprintf or vsyslog
    //vprintf(format, args);
    vsyslog(LOG_WARNING, format, args);
    va_end(args);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    // if I remove at least one of the function args or an %s in the string, the segfault does not happen
    doLog(1, 2, 3, "Format with args %s , %s", "1", "2");

    return 0;
}
```

What's going on here? Why does the second call to vprintf or vsyslog causes the segfault and why does it happen only with this specific number of function arguments? Even if I remove some arguments to avoid the segfault, still the output is wrong the second time.

Some information about my environment:

- OS: (as given by `uname -a`) Linux lexdeb 3.16.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.16.7-ckt25-2+deb8u3 (2016-07-02) x86_64 GNU/Linux (lexdeb is just the hostname)
- gcc version 4.9.2 (Debian 4.9.2-10)
- the program is in main.c file
- [compilation log](http://pastebin.com/raw/Fgn4iiDs)

Comment: You might want to read the manpage for `va_copy`.

Comment: You always should compile with `gcc -Wall` and very often also with `-g`

Comment: @EOF Thanks, that makes sense. Does it mean that v* functions themselves do not call va_copy to ensure safe processing of args?

Comment: @JustAMartin If you don't use the `va_list` multiple times, copying it is a waste of time. If the `v*printf()`-family copied the `va_list` argument, you could not avoid this waste of time.

Answer (score 3):

From `vprintf` man page:

```
int vprintf(const char *format, va_list ap);
```

> (...) Because they invoke the `va_arg` macro, **the value of `ap` is  undefined after the call**. See `stdarg(3)`.

So when you reach:

```
vsyslog(LOG_WARNING, format, args);
```

The `args` is undefined, leading to undefined behaviour.

Comment: Yet it also says that they don't call `va_end` and the caller needs to call `va_end`.